# Count down by seconds to a specific weekday

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, time, nsdate

I am trying to code a countdown to a specific day in the week. 
I want to display the current weekday and the remaining seconds to Wednesday.

I'm able to code the first part, but even after half day searching for a solution, I can't handle the second part.

This is what I have now:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [countdownLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:128.0]];
    countdownLabel.text = @"What day ist it?";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)updateLabel {
    NSDateFormatter* theDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [theDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [theDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    countdownLabel.text =  [theDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at both the NSDate and NSDateFormatter classes, they are rich with routines to do this sort of thing.

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSDateFormatter * df = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm" options:0 locale:usLocale];
NSDate * newyear = [df dateFromString:@"2012-01-01-00:00"];
NSTimeInterval seconds = [newyear timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Haven't tried to compile the above, but it should give you the seconds.  You should be able to look at the NSDateFormatter docs to easily find the day in the week.

Comment: thanks, i did that already. my problem is, that i would be able to code a countdown to the next year's new year. but as i want to count down to a specific day in the week, from any day in the week, i'm lost.